# Subversion 1.8.8 doesn't work with Java svn libraries

Tags: java, apache-ant

I'm running an up-to-date 14.04 installation. In a Java project built with Ant, I'm using the `<svn>` task to grab the current revision information. I've got (as far as I can tell) up-to-date versions of the "svnClientAdapter.jar" and "svnant.jar" libraries, and I've got the `libsvn-java` library installed for the JNI version of the adapter.

After doing the 13.10 -> 14.04 upgrade, I was told by `svn` that I needed to run `svn update` because the version of the runtime was ahead of the stuff in my checked-out tree. After doing *that*, I get errors from the `svn` ant task:

```
  [svn] <WcVersion> started ...
  [svn] svn: E155021: This client is too old to work with the working copy at
```

So what's up? Judging from various old questions it seems like this isn't a new phenomenon.

Answer (score 1):

Built an updated `svnClientAdapter.jar` and that did the trick. It's super-easy to do:

```
svn co http://subclipse.tigris.org/svn/subclipse/trunk/svnClientAdapter/ svnClientAdapter
```

to check out the current source, and then just `ant` to build. The source includes a bunch of other stuff but `svnClientAdapter.jar` is dropped ready-to-use into a build directory.

Probably a good idea to check [the project site](http://subclipse.tigris.org/svnClientAdapter.html) in case my URL above bit-rots.

Comment: The Subversion server now requires user credentials. Supply `--username=guest --password=` to be able to check out.